# mvc json product list

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to return a JSON list in my controller. Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
 public JsonResult GetProduct(){
        List<product> Productlist = new List<product>();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Productlist.Where(x => x.active == true));

        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

return empty = "[]"

Comment: Probably you can escape `== true` part in `Where(x => x.active == true)`. If `active` is of Boolean type, simply use `Where(x => x.active)`.

Answer (score 1):

You must fill your Product List;

```
private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext(); 
// DatabaseContext -> Your Database's Context Name

public JsonResult GetProduct(){
    List<product> Productlist = db.ProductsDB.ToList();
    // ProductsDB -> Your Product Model Name

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Productlist.Where(x => x.active == true));

    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you did't add products to your empty list

```
List<product> Productlist = new List<product>();
```

You need to add products to your list or get it from DB :

```
public JsonResult GetProduct(){
    List<product> Productlist = new List<product>();

    // add new product
    Productlist.Add(new Product());

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Productlist.Where(x => x.active == true));

    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```